# In a logo, is it okay to break the company name in two lines as needed?

Tags: logo, typography, branding

I have been asked to create visual identity for a new company. Their name is really long (think 12+ letters). They use several words together as one word. But there's also not an even number of letters. So I was thinking to separate the words in two lines for the larger size of logo and put in one line in small compact sizes. Is this practice okay? They are not going for lettermarks by the way -- I need to use the full name.

Comment: The only right answer is to check with the client if they're ok with that.

Comment: Perfectly OK, technically. Here's some companies who did just that: http://www.jamesgood.co.uk/blog/long-company-names-their-long-logos

Comment: Don't forget there are different measures. Condensed type was built for these design applications.

Answer (score 9):

My take as a multi-decade graphic designer?

It's fine if the name makes it the best approach visually, and if you've no existing brand definitions or logos to conflict with. If there are extant marks, you may end up having to redesign all of them if what you design is stronger and better done.

This designer's site gives some really clear thinking and examples of approaches to longer names - both long single line and stacked (worth a look- link below) and she *clearly* doesn't believe you can't version for different aspect ratios and text form lockups - in fact she recommends it as a good design option to present to clients, and her examples and work look pretty darn solid to me:

https://www.jessicajonesdesign.com/long-logos-with-long-company-names/

[image]

[image]

If you look at various assemblages of good or striking logos, you'll notice that somewhere between a quarter and a third of them tend to be stacked, so I think the real answer is: If you design something compelling, elegant and clearly differentiable, then go with it!

https://mayvendev.com/blog/50-fantastically-clever-logos

Comment: +1 for the word differentiable.

Comment: Ignore the work of anyone else until you squeeze as many designs out of your brain as you can. Rinse. Repeat. Only after you have many designs, look at others.

Answer (score 4):

There is no rule against splitting multiple words or even a single word across multiple lines. It is a design choice like any other that should have a clear intent and plan and you should be prepared to sell the idea to the client.

The client may be strongly against splitting their company name (if it is multiple words joined into one).

[image]

Comment: Yes, Microsoft comes in mind first but their name is even longer. I thought about the Jetbrain logo.

Comment: That's not a good example, as when Microsoft used the first logo it was actually called Micro-Soft.

Answer (score 3):

There are no rules; but, there are some "best practices."
The concept behind using a logotype is to provide a consistent, visual association with the brand image of the entity.
When you version a "bug," by changing its colour, size, location, and/or position; you're diluting the consistent repetition necessary to form the association. The unreinforced "sound" of the word-mark must carry the burden of the behavioural change.

Every once in a while, a logo will be changed due to some management decision to re-brand themselves. The most compelling evidence of this change is the new logo in a promotional blitz announcing the intent.

It's a good idea, when designing a logo to offer variation for different application corporately. A good example of this is monochrome for internal use or reverse for low-key (charity sponsorship) use. Then the variations are under your control and you can influence its proper use.

After you create your miracle, do carefully ensure that stacked or oblique letter combinations don't create unintended "words" or shapes in different languages/cultures.

So long as you preserve the marketing image of the entity, most anything goes.

Answer (score 2):

From a design point, your client's unusually long name could give them a big advantage of being unique.

Standing out from the rest of the field is what it's all about.

I would encourage you to play with alternatives to enhance or exaggerate the very thing that makes this design difficult to create.

For Example: Imagine if the letters in your logo became squashed together near the end of the word using progressively more condensed type. This would make the seemingly excessive length of the word a design feature.

Even a strange-sounding or difficult-to-pronounce names are fun because they're not plain-vanilla and don't follow the crowd. "With a name like Smuckers, you've got to be good."

Congratulations, you have a wonderful opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with @RizwanAKH: in graphic design there's no rules, specially after the 90's deconstructivism. You can build the logo rules for the company you are working for. One of the most exciting points of graphic design is to start from a rule and try to break it or use it as a conceptual axis of your design. If you believe in that new rule, this will be an excellent factor for selling your logo. Hope this help.

[image: Responsive logo]